# Why isn't my sign up form working, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

So I've got 2 sign up forms, 1 for student and 1 for tutor. But they aren't working and I want to know what's wrong with my code?? Here is my code for the routes file:

```
@app.route('/studentsignup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def studentsignup():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('studentdashboard'))
form = studentsignup()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
    user.set_password(form.password.data)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You are now a registered user!')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
return render_template('studentsignup.html', title='Student sign up', form=form)
@app.route('/tutorsignup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tutorsignup():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('tutordashboard'))
form = tutorsignup()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
    user.set_password(form.password.data)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You are now a registered user!')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
return render_template('tutorsignup.html', title='Tutor sign up', form=form)
```

Here is my code for the forms file:

```
class studentsignup(FlaskForm):
firstname = StringField('First name', validators= 
[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=20,message=None)])
surname = StringField('Surname', validators= 
[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=20,message=None)])
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), 
Email(),Length(min=2,max=50,message=None)])
username = StringField('Username', validators= 
[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=20,message=None)])
password = PasswordField('Password', validators= 
[DataRequired(),Length(min=8,max=20,message=None)])
password2 = PasswordField(
    'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), 
EqualTo('password'),Length(min=8,max=20,message=None)])
type = 'student'
submit = SubmitField('Register')

def validate_username(self, username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
    if user is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

def validate_email(self, email):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
    if user is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

The tutor sign up form is the same except type is tutor.

Here is the code for the form in the student sign up page:

```
<form action="" method="post" >


<div class="container">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <p>
    {{ form.firstname.label }}<br>
    {{ form.firstname(size=50) }}<br>
    {% for error in form.username.errors %}
    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
    {% endfor %}
</p>
<p>
  {{ form.surname.label }}<br>
  {{ form.surname(size=50) }}<br>
  {% for error in form.username.errors %}
  <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
  {% endfor %}
</p>
<p>
{{ form.email.label }}<br>
{{ form.email(size=120) }}<br>
{% for error in form.email.errors %}
<span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
{% endfor %}
</p>
    <p>
        {{ form.username.label }}<br>
        {{ form.username(size=64) }}<br>
        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    
    <p>
        {{ form.password.label }}<br>
        {{ form.password(size=128) }}<br>
        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.password2.label }}<br>
        {{ form.password2(size=128) }}<br>
        {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
```

Here is the error message that I get on the page when I try to go onto both of the pages: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGsaZ.png)

Here is the error which I got in the console :

```
[2021-06-11 15:41:01,868] ERROR in app: Exception on /studentsignup [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 37, in studentsignup
    form = studentsignup()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 37, in studentsignup
    form = studentsignup()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 37, in studentsignup
    form = studentsignup()
  [Previous line repeated 970 more times]
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 35, in studentsignup
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 345, in _get_user
    if has_request_context() and not hasattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user'):
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 192, in has_request_context
    return _request_ctx_stack.top is not None
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 168, in top
    return self._local.stack[-1]
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    return self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2021 15:41:01] "←[35m←[1mGET /studentsignup HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
[2021-06-11 15:51:24,710] ERROR in app: Exception on /tutorsignup [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 50, in tutorsignup
    form = tutorsignup()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 50, in tutorsignup
    form = tutorsignup()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 50, in tutorsignup
    form = tutorsignup()
  [Previous line repeated 970 more times]
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 48, in tutorsignup
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 345, in _get_user
    if has_request_context() and not hasattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user'):
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 192, in has_request_context
    return _request_ctx_stack.top is not None
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 168, in top
    return self._local.stack[-1]
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    return self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2021 15:51:24] "←[35m←[1mGET /tutorsignup HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
```

Comment: please fix your indentation of your python code

Comment: Rename your form function as it’s the same name as the route function. Hence calling the same function and getting the max recursion depth!

Comment: it works now but it the type doesn't go into the database so what can I do about that??